# How to sort postgres table in the command line?

Tags: postgresql

I'm viewing a table in my command line but I'm not sure how it's sorted:

[image]

I use the `TABLE "Notification";` command to display the rows in the table. Any tips on how to sort the display of this table? All my searches show how to sort a table result in a actual postgres query.

Comment: You have to run an actual PostgreSQL query with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Data in SQL tables is not ordered so you need specify an `ORDER BY` to sort by your desired field(s). `TABLE` is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM some_table`, so `TABLE  "Notification" ORDER BY some_fld`. I would get into the habit of using `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the rows by a certain order the ORDER BY is used.

For example (In your case):

```
SELECT id, watched FROM schema_name.notification ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This will sort the table by id ascending, but it can also be sorted decending by using DESC instead of ASC.

I hope this helps.